# Does anyone recognize this kind of hash/encryption?

Tags: javascript, encryption, hash

I'm doing a test for a company. In a javascript file, I've found the following:

```
contactEmail:"ZmFzdHRyYWNrK291cl9mYWNlYm9va19pZEBzbWFydGx5Lmlv", 
instructions:"Q29uZ3JhdHVsYXRpb25zLCB5b3UgaGF2ZSBhbG1vc3QgY29tcGxldGVkIHRoZSBGYXN0IFRyYWNrLiBBcyB0aGUgbGFzdCB0aGluZywgZmlndXJlIG91dCB0aGUgY29tcGxldGUgY29udGFjdCBhZGRyZXNzIGFuZCBzZW5kIHVzIGFuIGludHJvZHVjdGlvbiBlbWFpbC4gV2UgYXJlIGludGVyZXN0ZWQgdG8gaGVhciB3aGF0IHlvdSBoYXZlIGRvbmUgc28gZmFyLg=="
```

Does anybody have any idea what kind of encryption this is so I can decrypt it?? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Others have answered your question, but in case you're curious how you might come to this conclusion yourself: base64 encoding is pretty common on the web, and a good indication of it is the double equals sign at the end of the string. So if you see that, chances are it could be base64, so run it through window.atob and see what pops out. (Note that this doesn't mean all base64 encoded strings have an equals sign at the end)

Comment: Not sure how responsible this is, if this is supposed to be selecting applications, and you have just outsourced that work to the internet, not demonstrated your own skill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are base64 encoded strings.  They can be decoded using [`window.atob("...")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/atob). They read:

```
contactEmail: "fasttrack+our_facebook_id@smartly.io", 
instructions: "Congratulations, you have almost completed the Fast Track. As the last thing, figure out the complete contact address and send us an introduction email. We are interested to hear what you have done so far."
```

To extend what Matis said in the comments, the most common indicator of a base64 string is the trailing `=`.  This is just padding, since base64 string lengths are a multiple of 4.

For example:

```
window.btoa("a")       : YQ==         // 4
window.btoa("abc")     : YWJj         // 4
window.btoa("abcd")    : YWJjZA==     // 8
window.btoa("abcdefg") : YWJjZGVmZw== // 12
```

Comment: @Millica If I knew that a candidate for a job posted my entry test on StackOverflow, I wouldn't even consider, for a moment, hiring the candidate.  Just something to think about.

Comment: How long until the followup question: "How do you find a company's Facebook ID?"

Answer (score 1):

This is Base64 encoded text...

Answer (score 1):

it's encoded using base64.

here is the decoded value

```
contactEmail:"fasttrack+our_facebook_id@smartly.io",

instructions:"Congratulations, you have almost completed the Fast Track. As the last thing, figure out the complete contact address and send us an introduction email. We are interested to hear what you have done so far."
```

Use any base64 decoder to decode. you can use https://www.base64decode.org/